# Why is my ASP.NET Web API with Identity 2 not granting me access to protected resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2, bearer-token

I have a Web API using Identity 2. It seems to authenticate me fine, and the `/Token` endpoint returns what I deserialize to an `AuthTicket` instance, with contents much like:

```
AccessToken: "averylongtoken"
Expires: {2016/12/12 8:19:22 AM}
ExpiresIn: 1209599
Issued: {2016/11/28 8:19:22 AM}
TokenType: "bearer"
Username: "myusername"
```

Then, when I send a request like:

```
var response = await Client.GetAsync("api/appt/3/true", cancellationToken);
```

and `Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` looks like:

`Bearer theSameVeryLongToken`

I still get a `401 - Not authorized`. What could be wrong here? Could it be that the Web API is somehow not receiving or properly decrypting the bearer token? When I set a break-point in the API, and examine the `User` property in the controller action, all its properties are null or default, but it has one `ClaimsIdentity`, whose properties are also all null or default, and its `Claims` collection is empty.

Do I manually have to set all claims vs. only my custom ones? I would have thought `ApplicationOAuthProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` would at least add a claim such as the user name or id.

Comment: If you run your request in Fiddler, do you see your token passed in, in the Request headers? And also what do you see in the Request Context in your OAuthProvider class in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method?

Comment: For some reason I don't see any requests captured with my API url. When I set a filter to only the host `localhost:51999`, my API, and run a post request from the client, nothing is captured. I don't see any request context in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, only a `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext`, and isn't this method called from the `/Token` endpoint, to sign the user in. This all works fine, as I clearly stated, on login I get back a good response from `/Token`, with an auth token, but it won't be in the headers in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed all code again, somehow had lost the line that added the auth token to the request headers. Inspecting these headers before sending the request easily confirmed this, and it was easily fixed.